# Input from keyboard in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, raw-input

I write a simple factorial function in python to know the factorial of n . As like we given n and it shows the factorial of n . But the problem is , i use raw_input function to get the value of n. But can't work with that . What can i do to do with raw_input ?

Comment: Paste your code, so that people can understand your issue clearly..

Comment: Can you accept my answer if you find it correct?! I also suggested the same what @XYZ Programmer suggested, and I answered before him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the default string type to int

```
val = raw_input()    #val accepts a string 

val = int(raw_input())   #val takes integer input
```

Comment: That's exactly what I answered.

Comment: You could have at least provided an example supporting your answer instead of down voting.

Answer (score 1):

Your factorial function probably takes an integer as input.

However, raw_input returns a **string**.

So you either need to convert the returned string to an integer.
By using **int()**.

Or you can directly use **input()** which returns an integer in Python2.

Comment: `input()` returns a string in python 3 so your last line makes no sense (plus using`input()` in python 2 is a really bad idea)

Comment: My bad, I will edit it. But why's using input() in python2 a really bad idea?

Comment: because input wil evaluate whatever the user inputs as a python line. So if they do exit(), for example, the program closes, just like that.

Comment: @AyushMishra if you type in `with open(__file__,"w") as f:f.write("all gone")` from a python2 `input()` it deletes your program file

Comment: sorry that would raise a SyntaxError, if you wrote `open(__file__,"w").close()` it would erase the file.

Comment: Woah! Never knew that. Just read that it uses eval.